# Variable works only with echo

Tags: php

Somebody could answer why I can get the value in the `echo $novoTituloSlug;`.
But, I get nothing in the line `$novalinhas .= "<link>http://localhost/votanalei/" . $novoTituloSlug . "</link>" . "\r\n";` and below.

```
function ObterIDs($string) {
    $res = preg_match('~class="artigo" id="([\w]+)"~i', $string, $IDs);
    if ($res == 1){
            return $IDs[1];
    } else {
            return "";
    }      
}

$linhas = explode("<ul", $documento);

$novalinhas = "";

foreach ($linhas as $novalinha){

    $novoTituloSlug = ObterIDs($novalinha);
    echo $novoTituloSlug . "<br>"; // Apenas para teste.

    $novalinhas .= "<link>http://localhost/votanalei/" . $novoTituloSlug . "</link>" . "\r\n";
    $novalinhas .= "<wp:post_name>" . $novoTituloSlug . "</wp:post_name>" . "\r\n";
}


$file = fopen("test.txt","w");
$results = fwrite($file,$novalinhas);
fclose($file);
```

With var_dump($novoTituloSlug); below the echo line, i got:

```
string '' (length=0)

artigo1

string 'artigo1' (length=7)

artigo2

string 'artigo2' (length=7)

artigo3

string 'artigo3' (length=7)
```

In the function ObterIDs, if I remove the content and paste just return "teste"; then he will print me the value.

Comment: What is the **exact** output of: `var_dump($novoTituloSlug);` ?

Comment: I answer in the question, but I got:  string '' (length=0) / artigo1 / string 'artigo1' (length=7) / artigo2 / string 'artigo2' (length=7) / artigo3 / string 'artigo3' (length=7)

Comment: In the function ObterIDs, if I remove the content and paste just `return "teste";`  then he will print me the value.

Comment: Your problem is hard to debug because it lacks enough information to be reproducible. Please also add the contents of `$documento`.

Comment: Is just a string: $documento = '< ul class="artigo" id="artigo1">
 < li>
 < p>Art. 1º  Salvo disposição contrária, a lei começa a vigorar em todo o país quarenta e cinco dias depois de oficialmente publicada.< /p>
 < /li>
 < /ul>';